# PHP read a large file line by line and string replace

Tags: php, string, replace, large-files

I'd like to read a large file line by line, perform string replacement and save changes into the file, IOW rewriting 1 line at a time. Is there any simple solution in PHP/ Unix?
The easiest way that came on my mind would be to write the lines into a new file and then replace the old one, but it's not elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not such a bad solution to use the temporary file in most cases.

```
$f='data.txt';
$fh=fopen($f,'r+');
while (($l=fgets($fh))!==false) file_put_contents('tmp',clean($l),FILE_APPEND);
fclose($f);
unlink($f); 
rename('tmp',$f);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there're only 2 options

1. Use memory

Read, replace then store the replaced string into memory, once done, overwrite the source file.

2. Use tmp file

Read & replace string then write every line immediately to tmp file, once all done, replace original file by tmp file

The #1 will be more effective because IO is expensive, use it if you have vast memory or the processing file is not too big.

The #2 will be a bit slow but be quite stable even on large file.

Of course, you may combine both way by writing replaced string **by chunk of lines** to file (instead of just **by line**)

There're the simplest, most elegant ways I can think out.

Comment: That's right for small files RAM, for large ones a temporary file